# Weird error with if command

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed, cmd

I just finished a batch file. When I run it I face a weird error! Here is the first code for starters:

```
findstr    "ro.product.model="     build.prop     >tmp.txt
cscript "sed.vbs" "tmp.txt"     "ro.product.model=" ""
set /p device=>tmp.txt
del "tmp.txt"
cd C:\Kitchen\WORKING_FOLDER\system
echo Is your device a MediaTek (MTK) device?
set /p remt= y or n?
if %remt%==y goto mk
if %remt%==n goto no

:no

if %device% == GT-I9001 (

set bootimg=/dev/block/mmcblk0p8

goto bdrom

)
```

This is just one there are about 67 of them. When I execute and select `n` to advance program exits with error:

```
( was unexpected at this time
```

I tried removing brackets etc, nothing worked! Even the syntax is also correct of the command I can't understand where I am making mistake.

Comment: Your ˙%device%˙ results to an empty string, so wrong syntax in `if  == GT-I9001 (` occurred.

Comment: You have the redirection wrong when setting `device`. You should take stdin from the file, e.g. `set /p device="" <tmp.txt`.

Comment: How can i correct it? @eryksun i am kind of new sorry can you please elaborate for me

Comment: @YaMan: he already did. Read his comment again.